# Implementing Attention in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to check if my attention implementation is correct in TensorFlow.

Basically, I am using the attention mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06664v1.pdf. (Just the baseline attention, not the word-for-word attention). So far I implemented it without using the last hidden state h_N.

```
def attention(hidden_states):
    '''
    hidden states (inputs) are seq_len x batch_size x dim 
    returns r, the weighted representation of the hidden states by attention vector a

    Note:I do not use the h_N vector and also I skip the last projection layer. 
    '''
    shape = hidden_states.get_shape().as_list()

    with tf.variable_scope('attention_{}'.format(name), reuse=reuse) as f:
        initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()

        # Initialize Parameters
        weights_Y = tf.get_variable("weights_Y", [self.in_size, self.in_size], initializer=initializer)
        weights_w = tf.get_variable("weights_w", [self.in_size, 1], initializer=initializer)

        # Equation => M  = tanh(W^{Y}Y)
        tmp = tf.reshape(hidden_states, [-1, shape[2]])
        Y = tf.matmul(tmp, weights_Y)
        Y = tf.reshape(Y, [shape[0], -1, shape[2]])
        Y = tf.tanh(Y, name='M_matrix')

        # Equation => a = softmax(Y w^T)
        Y = tf.reshape(Y, [-1, shape[2]])
        a = tf.matmul(Y, weights_w)
        a = tf.reshape(a, [-1, shape[0]])
        a = tf.nn.softmax(a, name='attention_vector')

        # Equation => r = Ya^T
        # This is the part I weight all hidden states by the attention vector
        a = tf.expand_dims(a, 2)
        H = tf.transpose(hidden_states, [1,2,0])  
        r = tf.matmul(H, a, name='R_vector')
        r = tf.reshape(r, [-1, shape[2]])

        # I skip the last projection layer  since I do not use h_N
        return r
```

This graph compiles, runs and trains properly. (loss is decreasing etc) but the performance is lower than I would expect. I would appreciate if I could get a check if I'm doing it right.

Generally,

1) For multiplications that are [?, seq_len, dim] matrix multiplied by [dim, dim]. Is it correct to use tf.reshape from [?, seq_len, dim] to [-1,dim] and apply matmul of shapes [-1, dim] with [dim, dim] and then reshape back to [?, seq_len, dim] after matmul?

2) I notice I obtain (?, seq_len) for a, the attention vector. So I am required to do (?, seq_len) x (?, dim, seq_len).

Is it correct to cast and expand_dims from (?, seq_len) to (?, seq_len, 1) and then do a matmul (I think this was what batch_matmul does in previous versions).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure `tf.einsum` in TF1.0 is implemented efficiently, but it would make the computation quite elegant.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 3
seq_len = 5
dim = 2
# [batch_size x seq_len x dim]  -- hidden states
Y = tf.constant(np.random.randn(batch_size, seq_len, dim), tf.float32)
# [batch_size x dim]            -- h_N
h = tf.constant(np.random.randn(batch_size, dim), tf.float32)

initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
W = tf.get_variable("weights_Y", [dim, dim], initializer=initializer)
w = tf.get_variable("weights_w", [dim], initializer=initializer)

# [batch_size x seq_len x dim]  -- tanh(W^{Y}Y)
M = tf.tanh(tf.einsum("aij,jk->aik", Y, W))
# [batch_size x seq_len]        -- softmax(Y w^T)
a = tf.nn.softmax(tf.einsum("aij,j->ai", M, w))
# [batch_size x dim]            -- Ya^T
r = tf.einsum("aij,ai->aj", Y, a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    a_val, r_val = sess.run([a, r])
    print("a:", a_val, "\nr:", r_val)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, I believe the attention mechanism would need the encoder and decoder outputs to work. I don't think it's just as simple as applying a softmax to the outputs of the encoder network.

Comment: @YellowPillow you are partially correct, this answer only covers the encoder part. However, Attention only refers to the operation going on with the Query, Value and the Key, and NOT the full transformer block that Vaswani et. al's paper covers.